# Loading UIView from NIB

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller V which is part of a story board. On its viewDidLoad method it attempts to load a few views from a NIB (not a storyboard). The idea is to "assemble" some of the view using these "subviews".

However, when I try to load a view like this:

```
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"x"
                                                owner:self options:nil];
```

I'm getting an exception saying 'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key yyy.'

This is because the view in the NIB has a custom view controller, which has an outlet to a component in this view, which is connected in the NIB properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

right click on your fileOwner `viewController` in interface builder and then delete `yyy` outlet, you have an outlet connection, which is not existed or deleted 
Update screenShote added 
[image: xoced interface builder]

Look at this screenshot the button has 2 outlets, but yyyy is not existed in the viewController. you should delete this outlet 
[image]

Comment: No, I have an outlet which is connected to the view controller of the view to be loaded from that NIB. The problem is somehow iOS thinks there ought to be an Outlet property defined for the viewcontroller which is loading the NIB too (if I add a property with the same name, the error disappears, but that's not a solution)

Comment: I think part of the problem is the owner is set to 'self', which is the view controller loading the NIB, not the view controller set as owner inside the NIB... I have to think. Putting some views in a NIB and load from there seemed to be such an attractive idea. I'd have added these to the storyboard, but alas, that's not possible (you can't add UIViews directly)

Comment: Yes, I got you, but that's not the problem. The problem is ownership as it seems. Viewcontroller A tries to load a NIB and A does not want to be the owner of this NIB (being owner as it seems means that the outlets are connected to the owner)

Comment: So how does one go about reusable views then. How to load views from a NIB without being the owner of that NIB. The NIB may contain multiple views, with different viewcontrollers for each...

Comment: @Janos do this then: NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"x"
                                                owner:nil options:nil];

Comment: Hm, interesting. And how will the outlets get connected then? I thought about the following approach: 1 such custom view in 1 NIB (the view has a custom view controller to connect some outlets to). Now, in the hosting view controller (the one loading the whole thing) I will instantiate the custom view controller, and set that as the owner when loading the NIB. Wonder if that would work, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, it will work. the owner can be any object, but the loader retains the view.